# WebSocket connection to 'ws:<URL>/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, prisma, graphql-subscriptions

Hi am having this problem, i try to make subscriptions with graphql in nextjs, but something is wrong and i dont have any idea how fix it. I am having websocket error - "WebSocket connection to 'ws:/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

You can check code here - https://github.com/LoQeN00/messenger-2.0.git

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dXss.png)

[graphql-setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nHaT.png)

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: please make sure that the links provided in the question is working

Answer (score 8):

I restarted my PC and this issue was resolved for me according to [this post on github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30491#issuecomment-972811344)

Comment: As in the link you shared, Neither I have any other middleware/proxy settings, restarting my computer fixed it. The answer was helpful. thanks.

Comment: For me it was enough to restart my browser or just re-open the as incognito (maybe an extension was interfering).

Answer (score 4):

I needed to remove

```
assetPrefix: "./"
```

from `next.config.js` so HMR worked and those warnings disappeared.
Problem was both in FF and Chrome for me.

Comment: I wonder why the issue comes because of `assetPrefix`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Nginx:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-12#hmr-connection-now-uses-a-websocket

```
location /_next/webpack-hmr {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```